# Android - custom MapView

Tags: android, dictionary, android-mapview

I am planning to enlarge my application funcionality with maps. I have seen two Map View possibilities. There is default MapView by Google and custom made MapView by OSMdroid. I have custom maps, that aren't supported. Is there any guide or any help, how to write my own MapView, which will accept my locally stored maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to show a 2D-scrollable view of some complex graphics, while trying to minimize memory usage? Maybe [this sample code](https://github.com/ldo/view_cache_demo_android) might help.